# SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored is not called when trying to rebuy

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, in-app-purchase

I am midway in implementing in app purchase (SONGS-non consumable - content delivery from my server ).

When i try to buy the already purchased item, i never received **SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored** delegate method get called.

I am always receiving **SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased** notification.But the Apple alert comes as " **You have already purchased this item, Tap ok to download**"but the **SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored** is not called at all.

In this scenerio , does this SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored wont get called?or is that a intended behaviour.

please let me know

Comment: did you solve this problem???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing this for non-consumable IAP restores as well. I think it is a sandbox issue.

Answer (score 0):

`SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` is only issued after you call `restoreCompletedTransactions`.

Since you mention the "you already bought" message, it means you didn't call this method, but are using the standard buy process instead. Getting `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` is expected in that case.

Comment: But how do you know when to call restoreCompletedTransactions? How do I know when a user selects to buy something if they have previously bought it without SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored being called?

Comment: According to the guide lines, an app with IAP should provide a 'Restore purchases' button, that will call `restoreCompletedTransactions`. This is useful when the user re-installs the app on a new device for instance. This is different from the behavior of a 'Buy' button, which will trigger a standard purchase, and can be disabled if the item has already been purchased.

Comment: Gilles, I ended up figuring out what I needed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16091874/1301654